# How come when I edit the /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh file nothing happens?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I create a container off the node docker image. Then I go into the container with bash and try to edit the entrypoint file but the changes I make inside don't get executed. Like I told it to make a directory in the root path of the container called `/app` I stop and start the container but the change doesn't happen. Here's the file

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

mkdir /app

# Run command with node if the first argument contains a "-" or is not a system command. The last
# part inside the "{}" is a workaround for the following bug in ash/dash:
# https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=874264
if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ] || { [ -f "${1}" ] && ! [ -x "${1}" ]; }; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you're making this change, the entrypoint script has already executed.  A container runs *one* process, and it's the entrypoint script; there's no way to re-run it without re-running the container.  If you `docker rm` the old container and `docker run` a new one, the change you made to the file will be lost.

As a matter of general process I'd suggest avoiding "going into the container".  If you need to make a change in a script like this, change it on the host, `docker build && docker run` a new image with the change, and then commit the changed file to source control.  If you change your application code, `npm test` it on the host, then `docker build && docker run` a new image, and commit the updated code and unit tests to source control.

For your particular use case, if the container should always contain a directory named `/app`, I'd recommend creating it in the image's Dockerfile rather than trying to create it dynamically when the container starts up.

```sh
FROM node:lts
RUN mkdir /app
...
```

More generally, your image should contain the filesystem layout and code you need to run your application.  For most Node applications I'd expect a Dockerfile to look something like

```sh
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
CMD node ./index.js
```

(where you also have a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) that excludes the host's `node_modules` tree.)

Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial describes this sequence in more detail, including a different Node-based example.

Comment: So the CMD is what is run every time the container is started or restarted? Also does the ```WORKDIR``` command make the directory if it doesn't already exist? And if I'm not supposed to go into the container how do I edit source code when I'm developing?

Comment: (1) Yes, the `CMD` is the single process the container runs.  (2) Yes, `WORKDIR` creates the directory.  (3) Since a Docker container has its own filesystem that's isolated from the host system, I don't find it a good match for a development environment.  Particularly for Node I've run into few version incompatibilities and installing it directly on the host is very easy, so I'd use a host Node environment for day-to-day development.

Comment: So you would only use a container when done with development?

Comment: It's useful for integration testing too; and you can use a non-container host development environment in combination with container-based data stores (run PostgreSQL and Redis in containers but do development on the host).